# geom_path() Scatterplot ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, tidyverse, scatter-plot

I am trying to create a connected scatterplot similar to the [one](https://i2.wp.com/www.stephanieevergreen.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/SecondarySplitUpdated.jpg)  and this has more [explanation](http://stephanieevergreen.com/two-alternatives-to-using-a-second-y-axis/)

Essentially, I am trying to show on one graph, the decline in the number of people within the labor force as measured by their numbers. The second graph would show changes in the unemployment rate within the same period.

This is my code:

```
# ggplot2 call:
Unemployment_Outflows %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=unemployment_rate, y=labor, label=year)) +
  # Custom the Y scales:
  scale_y_continuous() +
geom_line( color="grey") +
    geom_point(shape=21, color="black", fill="#69b3a2", size=3)
  geom_segment(aes(
                    xend=c(tail(unemployment_rate, n=-1), NA), 
                    yend=c(tail(labor, n=-1), NA)
                  )
      )
```

[image]
However, as you can see, neither the lines nor a shaded area are visible, and I am getting the following error:

"geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?"

year

change

change_perc

unemployment_rate

labor

*year
(chr)     labor      unemployment_rate
(dbl)         (dbl)

Q4 2015 8416681  0        NA
Q4 2016 8492965           12.34717
Q4 2017 7907511           12.83452
Q4 2018 6895514           12.74767
Q4 2019 6437891           12.01787
Q3 2020 6409070           15.44732

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `geom_text()`. No output shared as no data was included. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Code
Unemployment_Outflows %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=unemployment_rate, y=labor, label=year)) +
  # Custom the Y scales:
  scale_y_continuous() +
  geom_line( color="grey") +
  geom_point(shape=21, color="black", fill="#69b3a2", size=3)
geom_segment(aes(
  xend=c(tail(unemployment_rate, n=-1), NA), 
  yend=c(tail(labor, n=-1), NA)
)
)+geom_text(vjust=0.5,fontface='bold')
```

Using the data you shared, try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df %>% 
  mutate(year=factor(year,levels = unique(year),ordered = T)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=year,y=value,color=name,group=name))+
  geom_point()+geom_line()+geom_area(aes(fill=name),alpha=0.5)+
  facet_wrap(.~name,scales='free',nrow = 1)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'top')+
  labs(color='Var',fill='Var')
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(year = c("Q4 2015", "Q4 2016", "Q4 2017", "Q4 2018", 
"Q4 2019", "Q3 2020"), labor = c(8416681, 8492965, 7907511, 6895514, 
6437891, 6409070), unemployment_rate = c(0, 12.34717, 12.83452, 
12.74767, 12.01787, 15.44732)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thanks, I realize that I included the wrong links in my original post, I have just fixed it, but have a similar issue now.

Comment: @maa425 It looks like an issue with other package, try re starting a fresh session, and only load `ggplot2` and `dplyr` then run the code!

Comment: @maa425 Also change this line `ggplot( aes(x=unemployment_rate, y=labor, label=year))` by this `ggplot( aes(x=unemployment_rate, y=labor, label=year,group=1))`

Comment: Thanks, it fixed it! But it produces the three variables in one graph, while I am looking for something like this:
https://i2.wp.com/www.stephanieevergreen.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/SecondarySplitUpdated.jpg

I fixed the link in my original post as well

Comment: @maa425 Try this change `ggplot( aes(x=unemployment_rate, y=labor, label=year,group=year))` let me know if that works!

Comment: thanks, check the graph I just added. It is still producing the same error unfortunately.

Comment: @maa425 I need the data, use `dput(head(Unemployment_Outflows,100))` and paste the output in your question, editing it. Also change color to `black`. Without data I can not help you!

Comment: @maa425 I have added an update, please check if that works for you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223533/discussion-between-maa425-and-duck).